# groupby and join result has indices and data type included in output

Tags: python, pandas

The objective is to take a data frame that looks like this:

```
keywords    group
word1        x
word2        x
word3        x
```

with group and keywords as strings within a pandas dataframe.

and create a dataframe that looks like this:

```
x    |word1|word2|word3
```

This is my current code:

I have tried using a function:

```
def preprocessing(dataset, group, keywords):
    dataset[keywords] = dataset[keywords].replace(' ', '_', regex = True)
    df = dataset.groupby(group)[keywords].apply(lambda x: ','.join(str(x).split()))
    df = pd.DataFrame(df)
    df[keywords] = df[keywords].replace('_', ' ', regex = True)
    return(df)
```

(the .replace in there was done to make it easier to keep spaces through the .join piece)

and I have tried doing it like this:

```
data['keywords'] = ['|%s' %i for i in data['keywords']]
x = data.groupby('group')['keywords'].apply(lambda x: ''.join(str(x).split()))
```

What I am getting as output has two significant issues.

1. The output ends up looking as follows, with group as the index:

```
0|word1|word2|wordName:x,dtype:object
```

where the numbers appear to be the index numbers for the individual words and the final string ends with the descriptive details "Name:x,dtype:object"

2. For large datasets, it will only get the first 30 and last 30 results in the string with an ellipsis in the middle, almost like a preview.

```
27|28|29|30|...|-30|-29|-28|
```

What would be causing the weird formatting issues and the data loss? It looks to be an issue with the lambda function as every other piece works as anticipated. Is there another way of doing this that will not result in lost data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
df.groupby('group')['keywords'].apply(lambda x: '|'+'|'.join(x))
```

---

```
group
x    |word1|word2|word3
```

Comment: @scain glad it works, would you consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) the answer then :)